# Execute set of test methods in with multiple concurrent threads

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, concurrency

What would be a JUnit based code to run this 3 methods each as 10 concurrent threads.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class
@SpringBootTest
public class TestClass {


    @Test
    public void readFromDBOneRecord(){
       try {
         dbService.findOneByID("1");
       } catch (Exception error) {
             Assert.fail("Unexpected error occured .");
       }
    }

    @Test
    public void writeToDBOneRecord(){
       try {
             dbService.save(entity.builder()
                            .setID("1").setName("John").build())
       } catch (Exception error) {
             Assert.fail("Unexpected error occured .");
       }
    }

    @Test
    public void deleteDbRecord(){
       try {
          dbService.delete("1");
       } catch (Exception error) {
             Assert.fail("Unexpected error occured .");
       }
    }
}
```

In some cases some of the methods would throw exceptions. Like if the `delete` being executed before  `writeToDBOneRecord`. 
So the sequence would be say for only 3 threads per method e.g.:

```
OperationNr|| OperationName || [ThreadNr/total threads per method]OperationType

     1.        write        [2/3]w
     2.        read         [1/3]r
     3.        read         [3/3]r
     4.        delete       [2/3]d
     5.        read         [2/3]r
     6.        delete       [3/3]d ->exception no record
     7.        write        [1/3]w
     8.        write        [3/3]w ->exception record already present
     9.        delete       [1/3]d
```

**What would the code for executing this 3 test methods each in 10 concurrent threads (30 in total)?**

Comment: You want to do everything in parallel?

Comment: all the threads use the exact same ID which is 1 here?

Comment: I want each test method to be executed in defined number of threads. So e.g. I want to have 5 concurrent reader threads executed at the same time as 3 concurrent writter threads. So two test methods  executet concurrently by 8 threads in parallel.

Comment: "[2/3]" is thread ID - it says nr 2 out of 3 threads of a type, so its unique in as of eg read methods

Comment: I have made an EDIT and added a letter to express that each thread ID belongs to a specific method type (hrer read,write,delete)

Comment: Beware trying to find concurrency bugs by testing.  Just because some race condition doesn't cause a problem in your test rig does not mean that it won't cause a problem on some different day in some different JVM version on some different OS version on some different hardware (i.e., at a customer site.)

Comment: I am not after concurrency bugs testing. I am after testing data availability in my database cluster with multi threaded  clients.

Answer (score 4):

As you want to do everything in parallel, I would mix everything and rely on `CountDownLatch` instances to synchronize the threads as next:

```
@Test
public void testMultiThreading() throws Exception {
    // Total of reader threads
    int reader = 5;
    // Total of writer threads
    int writer = 3;
    // Total of remover threads
    int remover = 1;
    // CountDownLatch used to release all the threads at the same time
    final CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
    // CountDownLatch used to be notified when all threads did their task
    final CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(reader + writer + remover);
    // List in which we collect all the errors
    final List<Exception> errors = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    // Create all the reader threads and start them
    for (int i = 0; i < reader; i++) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    startSignal.await();
                    dbService.findOneByID("1");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    errors.add(e);
                } finally {
                    doneSignal.countDown();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
    // Create all the writer threads and start them
    for (int i = 0; i < writer; i++) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    startSignal.await();
                    dbService.save(entity.builder()
                        .setID("1").setName("John").build());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    errors.add(e);
                } finally {
                    doneSignal.countDown();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
    // Create all the remover threads and start them
    for (int i = 0; i < remover; i++) {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    startSignal.await();
                    dbService.delete("1");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    errors.add(e);
                } finally {
                    doneSignal.countDown();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }
    // Release the threads
    startSignal.countDown();
    // Wait until all threads did their task
    doneSignal.await();
    // If an error has been collected, print the stack trace and throws the
    // first error to make the test fail
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        for (Exception e : errors) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        throw errors.get(0);
    }
}
```

**NB:** If you want a given unit test to be executed by several concurrent threads, have a look to [contiperf](http://databene.org/contiperf) but it won't allow you to mix them as you want to achieve

Comment: Well it is not a JUnit but an interesting solution. While using it, how could I check each thread `bookService` methods results joined with the thread id?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, if you want to test the result of methods like findOneByID, you can add your assertion directly in the run method after calling the method, if the assertion fails, an exception will be thrown and then the test will fail. Yes I know it is not a real unit test but what you want to achieve is not really a unit test either

Comment: I think you are right about the methods. Yes it is really kinda not a unit test use case. I have just found some `aven-surefire-plugin` possibiliteis of running concurrent tests witch I will post if answering the problem. Thank you for your solution - upvoted of course.

Comment: AFAIK maven-surefire-plugin will simply allow you to run your tests in parallel nothing more. If you want a given unit test to be executed by several concurrent threads, have a look to contiperf http://databene.org/contiperf but it won't allow you to mix them

Comment: Have you looked at contiperf to run a single testcase multiple times, in separate threads?

Comment: Yup surefire gives you directive `<prarllel>` which as I understand it is not concurrent. I wil investigate on the `Contiperf` - thanks guyz. I think the code provided by @NicolasFilotto should be enough for the moment. 
I have not found any out-of-the-box support.